# Under what conditions is $p(x) = mx^d+x-n$ the minimal polynomial for a number $\alpha>1$?

Tags: field-theory, solution-verification, minimal-polynomials

> Suppose $\alpha > 1$ satisfies $p(\alpha)=0$ for
>
> $$p(x) = mx^d+x-n$$
>
> where $m,n$ are positive integers. Under what conditions can we conclude that $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$?

If $\alpha$ is rational we can't say anything more. Suppose $p(x)$ isn't minimal, then $\alpha$ has degree $p$ for some $p < d$. In this case we can use the fact that $\alpha^d \in Span\{1,\alpha,...,\alpha^{p-1}\}$ and $p(\alpha) = 0$ to get a second polynomial $p_2(\alpha) = 0$ with degree of $p_2$ smaller than $p$, contradicting minimality.

Does this argument hold? I think so, can you confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With these conditions $p(x)$ is minimal iff it's irreducible and I don't see how your argument actually produces the second polynomial $p_2$. In fact these polynomials are not always irreducible: for example, taking $m = 1, d = 4, n = 2^4 - 2 = 14$ we have

$$p(x) = x^4 + x - 14 = (x + 2)(x^3 - 2x^2 + 4x - 7).$$

$n$ was chosen precisely so that $p(-2) = 0$, and on the other hand this polynomial satisfies $p(1) = -12, p(2) = 4$ and so has a second positive real root in $(1, 2)$ by the IVT (necessarily irrational) which we can choose to be $\alpha$. The cubic factor above is irreducible, for example because it's [irreducible $\bmod 5$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E3+-+2x%5E2+%2B+4x+-+7+mod+5), or because it only has one irrational real root.

In a positive direction, if $m = -1$ and $d = p$ is an odd prime the resulting polynomials $p(x) = -x^p + x - d$ are essentially the [Artin-Schreier polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Schreier_theory) (substitute $x \mapsto -x$) and these are known to be irreducible if $p \nmid d$ (because then they're irreducible $\bmod p$).